# How to connect the frontend library to laravel?

Tags: laravel, webpack, frontend

how to properly connect third-party plug-ins when developing on laravel?

I need the fullpage.js library

1. downloaded it via npm
2. in the resources/js/bootstrap.js file I added require ('fullpage.js');
3. In the resources/js/app.js file I added

   $ (document) .ready (function () {
           $ ('. js-fullpage'). fullpage ({});
       });

I launch the project and I see in the console

```
app.js: 4655 jQuery.Deferred exception: $ (...). fullpage is not a function TypeError: $ (...). fullpage is not a function
    at HTMLDocument. <anonymous> (http: // localhost: 3000 / js / app.js: 770: 21)
    at mightThrow (http: // localhost: 3000 / js / app.js: 4371: 29)
    at process (http: // localhost: 3000 / js / app.js: 4439: 12) undefined

app.js: 770 Uncaught TypeError: $ (...). fullpage is not a function
```

as if it does not see the connection it's a library ..

and generally my call code from resources/js/app.js is why you are ABOVE than resources/js/bootstrap.js, although they are connected in a different order

my bootstrap file

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
} catch (e) {

}

window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found:https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

require('fullpage.js');
```

Comment: Please can you add your `bootstrap.js` file to your question.

Comment: @RossWilson added

Comment: Is `$ ('. js-fullpage'). fullpage ({});` before or after `require('./bootstrap')` in your `app.js` file?

Comment: @RossWilson AFTER

my app.js:
require('./bootstrap');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-fullpage').fullpage();
});

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to include it like

```
require('fullpage')
```

or you can try to pass full path

Comment: Cannot find module "fullpage"

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your `webpack.mix.js` and run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` depending on your environment:

```
mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'path/to/fullpage.js',
], 'public/js/app.js')
```

Comment: no, because the plugin is initialized in the app.js file, and the plug-in AFTER initialization is connected and there will be a similar error